# What is the difference between uncheck and uncheckAndWait commands in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using both the commands in my code, uncheck(locater) is working fine but uncheckAndWait(locater) giving me error as "[error] Timed out after 30000ms". Can anybody please help me...

```
$My code is
        <td>
        <td>uncheck</td>
    <td>id=_sections_ctl00_section_ctl00_copyContactInfo</td>
    <td></td>
and
        <td>
    <td>uncheckAndWait</td>
    <td>id=_sections_ctl00_section_ctl00_chkSendExclusiveOffers</td>
    <td></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect `uncheckAndWait` to do?  The `AndWait` part says "wait for the page to load", which is very likely **not** what you want.

Comment: Thanks for Response Ross.. But why uncheckAndWait giving me such error, it should execute successfully..

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  Not unless unchecking the checkbox causes the page to refresh.  Which is very unlikely.